# Como validar extension y tamaño de un archivo con java script

Tags: javascript, archivo, validación

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente código:

```js
 peticion.addEventListener("load",() => {
        const fileInput = document.getElementById('archivo');
        var filePath = fileInput.value, filesize = fileInput.size;

        alert (filesize);
     
        document.getElementById("fileSize").innerHTML = filesize;

});
```

El detalle es que tanto en la alerta como en el HTML solo me sale un 20, no importa el tipo y tamaño del archivo que seleccione, siempre es 20.  y requiero obtener el tamaño del archivo, para realizar una validación. otros datos que traigo por parametro y el nombre del archivo si me los muestra correctamente.

En el HTML lo presento así:
total size: 0
utilizando esta linea: `document.getElementById("fileSize").innerHTML = filesize;`

Haber si me pueden ayudar a resolver este detalle.

Gracias

Comment: No es tan sencillo validar una extension de manera correcta, quiza pienses que es facil, debido a que simplemente debes mirar que extension tiene el archivo al final, pero ten en cuenta que muchas vecez uno mismo puede cambiar la extension original de un archivo, haciendo que un archivo que originalmente era un documento se haga pasar por una imagen, aparte actualmente puedes quitar la extension del propio archivo en el nombre, haciendo que obtener la extension del archivo sea imposible de manera directa mediante `javascript`

Comment: Esto debido a que si intentas obtener la extension de un archivo que no tiene la extension definida en su propio nombre siempre te va a devolver como tipo: `application/octet-stream` el cual es un tipo generico binario que existe en cualquier tipo de archivo, es el tipo que se usa cuando el sistema no logra reconocer exactamente que tipo de archivo es.

Comment: Yo te recomiendo preguntar lo de las extensiones en ptra prgunta, ya que eso es tema aparte y dejar esta solo para el tamaño, ya que igual hay mchas maneras de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes cambiar

```
filesize = fileInput.size
```

por

```
fileInput.files[0].size
```

Ya que el componente html puede tener varios archivos, y así te aseguras de siempre obtener el tamaño del primero

```js
const fileSizeTypes = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];

let load = () => {
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('archivo');
  var filePath = fileInput.value,
    filesize = fileInput.files[0].size;
  let idx = Math.floor(Math.log(filesize) / Math.log(1024));
  console.log(filePath);

  document.getElementById("fileSize").innerHTML = `${(+(filesize / Math.pow(1024, idx))).toFixed(idx>0?2:0)} ${fileSizeTypes[idx]?fileSizeTypes[idx]:'??'}`;

};
```

```html
<input id="archivo" type="file" onchange="load()" />
<div id="fileSize"></div>
```

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente POR FIN!!! me muestra el valor que necesito,  la alerta me muestra: 46894128, para un archivo que en el directorio en Windows es de 45,796KB Gracias!!!!